# Drop all events after the first until that first event has been processed

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a button that opens a chatbot in a browser. The problem is that I don't directly have the address for the chatbot. I have to ask a second server for that address, so my button doesn't react immediately to a click.

I'd like it to not open two browser tabs if the button is clicked twice quite quickly.
I need something that looks a bit like Throttle, but instead of checking the time elapsed, checks whether the previous event that it let go by has terminated or not.

I suppose I could do this with a boolean check and a filter in the reactive pipeline, but I don't want to have to deal with thread safety on that boolean since I'm launching the process on a second thread.

For example I have a method that does something long, like calling an api to get an address :

```
private async Task<string> LongTask()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "a return value";
}
```

And I'd like to handle it one click at a time, dropping any other clicks that happen before the first event has finished processing a bit like :

```
var longTaskObservable = 
    Observable.FromAsync(LongTask) // Create observable from async method that returns one value
              .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default); // Run it on a background thread

bool inProgress = false;
Observable.FromEventPattern(btn, "Click") // On a click event
    .Where(_ => !inProgress)
    .Do(_ => inProgress = true)
    .SelectMany(longTaskObservable) // Start the long task observable and use its unwrapped values instead of the event args
    .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) // Exclude any results that are marked as invalid
    .ObserveOnDispatcher() // Set the thread of the subscribe method after to the ui thread
    .Subscribe(result => {
        LogWithThread("Got result '" + result + "' on thread {0}");
        inProgress = false;
    }); // Get the result
```

But that's not very clean or clear or modular and is easy to break.
It seems like it should be so simple to do.. I must be missing something here.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Can't you just disable the button when clicked and re-enable it at the end of the process ?

Comment: That's essentially what I outlined in my post. I was looking for a reactive-native solution if it exists. Or at least something more elegant

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do this:

- Processing the task synchronous - should only really be done for calls that are very fast. ~50ms
- Show a modal progress dialog - This will prevent any interaction with the UI until the operation is complete, but not freeze the UI. Best suited for long operations that can actually show progress, but may be adapted for tasks of varying length.
- Disable the button and enable it after the operation is complete - Keep in mind to use try/finally to ensure it is actually re-enabled. And that the application can handle any other button being pressed while the task is processing.
- Use a InProgress Flag, as in your example. If you are simply awaiting the task in the button handler, anything after the await will still run on the main thread, so it is perfectly thread safe.
- Ensure the button press is Idempotent. Typically the button would set some state, but only run the expensive operation if the state was changed.

Comment: They're all pretty decent solutions to the UI problem, but as you say we still have to handle any failure situation and I thought reactive might have some well thought out feature that copes with everything.
If we start adding error handling into the observables I declared it gets quite messy and very easy to break with subsequent changes.

Comment: I realise that this problem could be solved by using async/await on the event, but I have the ulterior motive of wanting to port this kind of reactive pipeline solution to F# where it's more at home and was wondering if within the scope of reactive there's a better way

Comment: For this particular example, i fail to see how Rx makes the problem simpler. I would personally probably stick to regular asyn/await and a try/catch for error handling.

Comment: I don't think it makes it easier, but as I said it's a part of trying to move this type of solution to F# where it's more natural